# Saving custom NSObject in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsobject, nskeyedarchiver

I'm having a modal entity file as below,

```
import UIKit
class MyProfile: NSObject {
   var userName : String = ""

    func initWithDict(dict: NSMutableDictionary) {
     self.userName =  dict.objectForKey("username") as! String
    }
}
```

Saving that entity by encoding as below,

```
    let myDict: NSMutableDictionary = ["username": "abc"]
    let myEntity:MyProfile = MyProfile()
    myEntity.initWithDict(myDict)
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(myEntity)
    userDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: "MyProfileEntity")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Getting that saved entity as below,

```
    let myEntity:MyProfile = MyProfile()
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    guard let decodedNSData = userDefaults.objectForKey("MyProfileEntity") as? NSData,
        myEntity = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(decodedNSData) as? MyProfile!
        else {
            print("Failed")
            return
    }

    print(myEntity.userName)
```

It's not working, having crashes and lot of syntax errors, I'm new to swift,

It's showing some syntax errors like **definition conflicts with previous value** in the `unarchiveObjectWithData` line. If I fix that error, then at the time of getting the entity from userdefaults it's crashing.

can anyone suggest how can I resolve it?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @ryantxr, it's showing some syntax errors like definition conflicts with previous value .....

Comment: If you want help, you need to be specific. Update your question with complete and exact error messages and point out the exact lines causing the errors.

Comment: @rmaddy, edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save custom object into user default, you must implement NSCoding protocol. Please replace your custom data model like this:

```
class MyProfile: NSObject,NSCoding {
var userName : String = ""

@objc required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){

    self.userName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("USER_NAME") as! String

}

@objc func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
  aCoder.encodeObject(self.userName, forKey: "USER_NAME")
}

init(dict: [String: String]) {

    self.userName = dict["username"]!
}

override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

}

Here is the code for saving and retrieving MyProfile object:

```
// Save profile
    func saveProfile(profile: MyProfile){
        let filename = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/Documents/profile.bin")
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(profile)
        data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)
    }
    // Get profile
    func getProfile() -> MyProfile?{

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/Documents/profile.bin")){

            let unarchiveProfile = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! MyProfile

                return unarchiveProfile

        } else{

            return nil

        }

    }
```

Now here is the code snippet how to use those method:

```
// Create profile object
let profile = MyProfile(dict: ["username" : "MOHAMMAD"])
// save  profile
saveProfile(profile)

// retrieve profile
if let myProfile = getProfile(){
    print(myProfile.userName)
}else{
    print("Profile not found")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can u pl give the save and retrieve syntaxes too...? Major issues on that part

Comment: Hi @NAZIK check my edited answer. Hope you will enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks again, but there is an error in ur above code, "incorrect argument label in call" while creating MyProfile - `let profile = MyProfile(dict: `...., How to fix that? I tried coder instead of dict but no luck...

Comment: It's working great, saved a lot of time, hope  it will help few others too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
let myEntity:MyProfile = MyProfile()
```

Then later on, do this:

```
myEntity = ...
```

When something is defined with 'let', you cannot change it.

Change to
    var myEntity: MyProfile?

It is possible that

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(decodedNSData)
```

is returning nil. You then proceed to force unwrapping by adding

```
as? MyProfile!
```

try changing this to

```
as? MyProfile
```

Then later, see if you got something back

```
if let myEntity = myEntity {
    print(myEntity.userName)
}
```